# To manage Xero/Quickbooks/Plooto staff members through api endpoints/SDK/third party apps

Tags: sdk, quickbooks, xero-api

I want to change below things via API, plugin, extension etc

1. 'Client access' for any user of quickbooks application
2. 'Edit Payees', 'Edit Banks', 'Edit users', 'Edit Payments' & 'Edit Company Details' checkboxes of various clients for any user for Plooto application
3. Xero Organisation Access' from the dropdown (Say Advisor) for Xero application

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

None of those platforms supports a way to change use roles through their APIs.

The reason you can't find a way to do this, is because it's not supported (it has  obvious security implications, so I wouldn't get your hopes up of it being supported anytime soon by any of those platforms).